# Webpage still getting re-directed to HTTPS after commenting out redirect parameters in the httpd.conf file

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

We set up a Linux webserver running Apache and it is using a SSL cert. We are in the process of putting this application behind a NS appliance so will need to move SSL to the NS.

Have a test server set up to test this with exact same config as production. Originally we have a virtual host set up in the `httpd.conf` file using port 80 and we use redirect parameters to redirect users to https.

I have commented out those parameters and restarted apache and restarted httpd service but I am still getting redirected. I cleared browser cache as well but still getting redirected. I cannot seem to figure out why? `httpd.conf` entry below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin systems@company.org
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName testserver02
# RedirectMatch permanent (?i)^/phpapp https://alias.company.org/phpapp
# RedirectMatch permanent (?i)^/appname https://alias.company.org/appname
# RedirectMatch permanent (?i)^/appname_form https://alias.company.org/appname_form
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You restarted apache *and* httpd? Do you have two services running? If you have two services installed, you might be editing the config for one while accessing the other.

Comment: Let me clarify the commands ran are below                           service httpd restart & apachectl restart

Comment: Are you 100% positive things are not cached? Check the output headers with `curl -I company.org` to see what exactly is happening. Also, check the `default` or `000-default` config to see what is in there as well.

Comment: $ curl -I hostname.company.org
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Wed, 12 Nov 2014 23:50:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 3985
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

]$ curl -I hostname.company.org/application
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 12 Nov 2014 23:50:48 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
Location: http://hostname/application/
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Answer (score 1):

To ensure you are not seeing cached behavior by client you can use telnet to make manual HTTP request at port 80 to check that you really get a redirect.

> telnet www.domain.tld 80

and request would look something like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.domain.tld
```

followed by two empty lines.

Seldomly, I have processes that does not stop when issuing the start/stop command. Check that service has stopped after issuing stop command,  if it's still running kill it before relaunching.

Comment: I believe the curl command above gives similar results.

Comment: yes, though curl can take into account some proxy settings ( e.g. the environment variable http_proxy )

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty clear, assuming you've restarted the correct instance--someone else is doing the redirect.  Assuming you're adding entries just for the VirtualHost, I'm going to assume that you're specifying these in a `conf.d` like directory.  Check other configs for similar settings, including the core httpd.conf.

The file is typically `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`, with the conf.d files located in `/etc/httpd/conf.d`, but this varies between Linux distributions.  You can also check for `.htaccess` files in your `/var/www/html` directory(ies).

Comment: Yes we are using the http.conf file to redirect to https. I have commented out the redirect parameters. We are not using a .htaccess file strictly http.conf (virtual Host). I have combed over the options in httpd.conf and have found nothing else out of the ordinary as it is basically defaults other than the virtual host parameters.

Comment: Try increasing the LogLevel--the `Redirect` option is handled by `mod_alias`.  Try increasing it to Debug level and make the call.  You may want to increase it to trace1 (or higher) to figure it out.